# "xfs_copy" equivalent for ext4?

Tags: ext4, xfs

I love xfs_copy's ability to clone an xfs file system from disk to disk. Is there an equivalent tool to clone an ext4 file system?

I've tried dump/restore, but it requires the destination file system to be created and mounted. So it is not an equivalent to xfs_copy.

What is the "xfs_copy" equivalent for ext4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ext4 wiki [suggests](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_VM_Images) `e2image -rap`.  The last two options are not otherwise documented; personally this would make me wary of using it.  The manual page only describes its use to send debugging information to the filesystem developers.

`partclone.ext4 --dev-to-dev` will also work.  partclone is third-party software, not included in common distributions.  It is part of the Clonezilla project, which is a very powerful disk imaging solution.  I believe it differs from xfs_copy in that it does not change the filesystem UUID.

I'm not sure why this model would be considered superior to dump/restore in principle.